# how to integrate machine learning models in flink to make predictions using python

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I am trying to make real time predictions on a dataset, how can i include svm, nb, and cnn on apache flink to make predictions/classifications in python.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at Flink ML? Looking at the operators, there are already multiple operators supported. It also includes examples on how to achieve this with PyFlink. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-ml-docs-release-2.1/docs/try-flink-ml/quick-start/ for more details

Comment: Thanks for the response, I saw the document you showed. However, I was unable to integrate the machine learning models to make predictions on the datasets consumed by Flink from Kafka. I will be happy if you can give me more assistance. I am using python.